# Why would the price of goods rise up after increased consumption due to the outbreak?

Tags: macroeconomics, supply-and-demand

On the wake of the COVID-19 outbreak, consumption of some goods will increase. 
But, my question is why so?

My understanding is that, since aggregate demand for these goods has increased, supply can't keep up and therefore prices will increase to compensate for the increased usage of means of producion.

But, this will be done under the assumption that these suppliers actually **want** to satisfy the customers who can't buy these products anymore (due to shortage).

What if these suppliers don't increase production? Wouldn't the prices stay the same (with the outcome of people not finding enough goods)?

Comment: Why would choosing not to increase production cause prices to not increase?

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku What would be the other factors leading to its increase, if I may ask?

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of supply and demand curves?

Comment: @user253751 I'm not assuming a price-induced increase of demand. Other than companies willing to make more or increasing their production capacity, I'm concluding that there is no reason for the price to go up.

Comment: @IliassA Increased demand causes prices to increase; increased supply causes prices to decrease.